# unable to create sparkcontext in sparkversion 2.0.1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I m have recently updated my spark version from 1.5 to 2.0.1. By python scripts stops working.

code in 1.5 which was working

```
sc=SparkContext(appName="YOGI")
```

Code modified in spark 2.0.1

```
sc =SparkContext().master("spark://107.110.74.58:7077").appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate()


File "/home/yogendra.s/codebase/processRawData.py", line 56, in <module>
    sc =SparkContext().master("spark://107.110.74.58:7077").appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate()
  File "/home/yogendra.s/.spark_update/spark_hadoop2_7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
  File "/home/yogendra.s/.spark_update/spark_hadoop2_7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 174, in _do_init
  File "/home/yogendra.s/.spark_update/spark_hadoop2_7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 259, in _start_update_server
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 420, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 434, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known



Content of my default.xml
spark.master                       spark://107.110.74.58:7077
spark.driver.memory                20g
spark.executor.memory              20g
```

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing your code:

> sc =
>   SparkContext().master("spark://107.110.74.58:7077").appName("Python
>   Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate()

You should try using `.setMaster` instead of `.master`

[Spark documents](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html) suggest:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

In your case try:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Python Spark SQL basic example").setMaster("spark://107.110.74.58:7077")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Note that I've removed the `.getOrCreate()` part